# Prove that $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int_E f(x,t)dx=\int_E \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)dx.$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:I\times E\to \mathbb R$ where $I$ is an interval. Suppose

- $x\longmapsto f(x,t)$ is integrable for all $t$.
- $t\longmapsto f(x,t)$ is derivable for a.e $x$, we denote the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$.
- There is $\varphi:E\to \mathbb R^+$ in $L^1(E)$ s.t. $$\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\right|\leq \varphi(x)$$
  for a.e. $x$.

Set $$F(t)=\int_E f(x,t)dx.$$
Prove that $$F'(t)=\int_E \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)dx,$$
for all $t$.

---

**Attempts**

We made the proof when $I$ is an interval of the form $[a,b]$ and $f$ is $\mathcal C^1([a,b])$. So the theorem is just a consequence of mean value theorem. I would like to prove this more general theorem. I did as follow :

Fix $t\in I$. We suppose first $I$ bounded. Since $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x,t+h)-f(x,t)}{h}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t),$$
there is $\delta>0$ s.t. $$|\frac{f(x,t+h)-f(x,t)}{h}|\leq \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\right|+1\leq \varphi(x)+1\in L^1(I).$$

Using DCT, we get $$\lim_{h\to 0 }\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h}=\int_E\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x,t+h)-f(x,t)}{h}dx=\int_E\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)dx.$$

**Q1)** Is it correct ?

**Q2)** How can I do when $I$ is not supposed bounded ?

Comment: I found this and thought it could be interesting ,though it doesn't give any proofs sadly http://planetmath.org/differentiationundertheintegralsign

Comment: I gave a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739209/proving-that-an-integral-is-differentiable/1740987#1740987). I think it is what you want.

Comment: @Mattos: The thing is I don't have the assumption that $\frac{f(x,t+h)-f(x,t)}{h}\leq \varphi(x)$ I just have $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\right|\leq \varphi(x).$ So I'm not sure the proof you made is adaptable here.